# Filtering options in a select via input searchbar doesn't work on safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filtering

I'm trying to filter the options that are shown in a select based on a search input, and it is working on chrome, mozzilla, edge and opera, but can't get it to work on safari.

The input

```
<input id="myInputSearchUsers"
       class="form-control" type="text"
       aria-label="Search" style="height: 30px;padding: 5px 10px;font-size: 12px;line-height: 1.5; 
       border-radius: 3px;width: auto;margin-inline-start: auto;margin-top: -30px;display: inline-block;"/>
```

The Select

```
<select th:multiple="true" id="availableUsers" class="form-control" data-type="dual-list-source" style="min-height: calc(50vh);">
    <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.username}" th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}"></option>
</select>
```

The js

```
var test = document.getElementById('myInputSearchUsers');
    test.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        alert("THIS IS WORKING");
        filterUsers();
        alert("THIS IS WORKING 2");
    });

    const filterUsers = () => {

        let filter = $("#myInputSearchUsers").val().toUpperCase();

        $.each($("#availableUsers").find("option"), (i, opt) => {
            alert("THIS IS ALSO WORKING");
            if ($(opt).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                $(opt).css("display", "");
            } else {
                $(opt).css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    };
```

All the alerts popup on safari as well but the options don't get filtered,
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!